# Xeams to Postfix Forwarder

Tags: postfix, email-server, mail-forwarding

I have a xeams mail server that has got forwarders setup to filter then forward mail onto a postfix server. The problem is that whenever I try send an email from the xeams server to an email address on the postfix server because they have the same domain name I get this error.

The email gets sent from user2@samesdomain.com to user1@samesdomain.com

```
2018-07-05 14:42:41,450 - [        86] ************ New (secure) connection to: (postfix server ip)
2018-07-05 14:42:41,450 - [        86] S <-- EHLO sub.samedomain.com
2018-07-05 14:42:41,668 - [        86] C --> 250-mx.samedomain.com
2018-07-05 14:42:41,668 - [        86] C --> 250-PIPELINING
2018-07-05 14:42:41,668 - [        86] C --> 250-SIZE 209715200
2018-07-05 14:42:41,668 - [        86] C --> 250-ETRN
2018-07-05 14:42:41,668 - [        86] C --> 250-AUTH PLAIN LOGIN
2018-07-05 14:42:41,668 - [        86] C --> 250-AUTH=PLAIN LOGIN
2018-07-05 14:42:41,668 - [        86] C --> 250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
2018-07-05 14:42:41,668 - [        86] C --> 250-8BITMIME
2018-07-05 14:42:41,668 - [        86] C --> 250 DSN
2018-07-05 14:42:41,668 - [        86] S <-- MAIL FROM:<user2@samedomain.com>
2018-07-05 14:42:41,712 - [        86] C --> 250 2.1.0 Ok
2018-07-05 14:42:41,712 - [        86] S <-- RCPT TO:<user1@samedomain.com>
2018-07-05 14:42:41,758 - [        86] C --> 553 5.7.1 <user2@samedomain.com>: Sender address rejected: not logged in
2018-07-05 14:42:41,758 - [        86] S <-- QUIT
2018-07-05 14:42:41,802 - [        86] C --> 221 2.0.0 Bye
2018-07-05 14:42:41,802 - [        86] ~~~~~~~~~~~~ Connection Ter
```

I am not to sure how to proceed is there a way to set my postfix server to ignore that and accept any emails?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply list your Xeams server IP in Postfix [`mynetworks`](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#mynetworks):

> `mynetworks` (default: see `postconf -d` output)
>
> The list of "trusted" remote SMTP clients that have more privileges
>   than "strangers".
>
> In particular, "trusted" SMTP clients are allowed to relay mail
>   through Postfix. See the [`smtpd_relay_restrictions`](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#smtpd_relay_restrictions) parameter
>   description in the [postconf(5)](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html) manual.